# how can a full sentence be a noun

Tags: sentence

"Of all the visual arts, architecture affects our lives most directly for it determines the character of the human environment in major ways."
I was reading an article and saw this sentence. I couldn't understand why this sentence is correct. Isn't "it determines..." a complete sentence itself?

Comment: In this use, *for* = for the reason that = because.

Comment: The sentence is fine. The main clause has "architecture" as its subject and "affects" as its verb.

Answer (score 0):

**It** is a pronoun, referring to **architecture**. Also notice the conjunction **for** before **it**.

Comment: Yeah but shouldn't it be "for its determining ..." ?

Comment: No. That construction is not grammatical. Note how the verbs match tense.